# ¿Cómo puedo generar una matriz zig zag de este tipo?

Tags: java, netbeans, fórmulas-de-matriz

Estoy trabajando en Java y tengo que hacer la impresión de una matriz que muestre los números del 0 al 16 de esta manera:

[[image: Matriz[1]]

El código que estaba tratando de usar es este, sin embargo me salen diferentes inconvenientes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numeros [][] = new int [4][4];
    boolean sube = true;
    int j = 0;
    int contador = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        contador ++;
        if (sube) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                numeros[j][i] = contador ++;                             
            }
            sube = !sube;
        } else if (!sube) {
            for (j = 3 - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                numeros[j][i] = contador ++;                                       
            }
            sube = !sube;
        }
        for (i=0; i <=3; i++){
            System.out.print(numeros[j][i] + "\t");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: **¿Que inconvenientes tienes?** revisa [ask]

Comment: Andres, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, trata de especificar el problema**, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes realizar la operación según el número de fila, es decir, si es par o impar.

Edito la respuesta para poner un código completo y funcionando, así como un enlace al final para poder probar.

```
public class matrixComplete{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numeros [][] = new int [4][4];
        int contador = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            if (i%2 == 0) { // Ascendente en pares
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    numeros[i][j] = contador;                             
                    contador ++;
                }

            } else { // Descendente en impares
                for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {
                    numeros[i][j] = contador;                                       
                    contador ++;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){

            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                System.out.print(numeros[i][j] + "\t");
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

Resultado:

```
0   1   2   3   
7   6   5   4   
8   9   10  11  
15  14  13  12
```

[Puedes testear el código aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo el zigzag inverso, es decir, empiezas bajando en vertical y vas subiendo al cambiar de linea horizontalmente. Además estas limitandolo a 3 en `i < 3` cuando tu objetivo es llegar hasta 4 filas/columnas.

Por ello cambiando el orden de `numeros[j][i]` por `numeros[i][j]`, ajustando bien los límites hasta donde quieres que lleguen y empezando en 1 y no en 0 se resuelve el problema.

Código con esto bien ajustado:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numeros [][] = new int [4][4];
    boolean sube = true;
    int j = 0;
    int contador = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (sube) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                numeros[i][j] = contador ++;                             
            }
            sube = !sube;
        } else if (!sube) {
            for (j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {
                numeros[i][j] = contador ++;                                       
            }
            sube = !sube;
        }
    }


    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            System.out.print(numeros[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el sistema reporto 2 respuestas, te sugiero realices una pero correctamente para evitar estos problemas, ya recuperé esta, saludos!