# Matriz con recorrido

Tags: c

He estado buscando distintos tipos de recorridos de matrices pero no he encontrado nada parecido al recorrido que necesito, adjunto una foto del recorrido.

[image: imagen]

Intente empezando con un recorrido completo de izquierda a derecha (como el comienzo) pero ni siquiera me salio, intente incluir un `for (j=9; j>=0; j--)` al resto del programa pero me salieron muchos números feos.

```
int main(void) { 
  int i,j;
  int x=-1;
  int mat[10][10];

  //bucle de matriz
  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    for(j=0; j<10; j++) {
      x += 1;
      mat[i][j]= x;
  }

  //impresion de la matriz 
  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    for(j=0; j<10; j++) {
      printf("%3d\t",mat[i][j]);
  }

  printf("\n\n");
}
```

Si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Nos puedes mostrar los "números feos, por favor?"

Comment: 0   1 32660   -359674985    0 4195952  0  10   1   9

Comment: Milagros, acabo de, literalmente, copiar y pegar tu código en [cplayground](https://cplayground.com/?p=duck-termite-monkey) y no me sale nada parecido a lo que reportas.

Comment: porque el código es la matriz sola, todo agregado que le puse después de eso salio mal.

Comment: Mira esta [pregunta y su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143819/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-generar-una-matriz-zig-zag-de-este-tipo). Tal vez te apunte en la dirección correcta. El recorrido es distinto, pero puedes ajustar el algoritmo para que siga el que tú quieres. Luego puedes responder tu propia pregunta con tu método.

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente algoritmo hace el recorrido que pretendes. Reasigno los valores a la matriz para que una vez que se imprima se vea que se ha seguido el recorrido:

```
void HacerRecorridoEnMatriz(int mat[][10])
{
    int nPos=0;
    // Primera parte del recorrido
    int xPos=0;
    for(int y=0; y < 10; y++)
    {
       do 
       {
           // Caculo la posición relativa en X
           xPos = nPos%4;
           if (y%2 != 0) xPos = 3 - xPos;
           // Modificamos el array para mostrar el recorrido que estamos siguientdo.
           mat[y][xPos] = nPos;
           nPos++;
       } while (nPos%4 != 0); // Sólo actuamos sobre 4 columnas
    }
    // Segunda parte del recorrido
    int yPos=9;
    for(int x=9; x > 3; x--)
    {
       do 
       {
           yPos = nPos%10;
           if (x%2 != 0) yPos = 9 - yPos;
        
           mat[yPos][x] = nPos;
           nPos++;
       } while (nPos%10 != 0); // Sólo actuamos sobre 10 filas
    }
}
```

Usamos la variable **nPos** pasa saber el número de casilla en curso y que tomará valores desde 0 hasta 99.

Luego la variable **xPos** nos permite saber la posición relativa (número de columna) dentro de la matriz cuando vamos conformando el recorrido. En la primera parte del recorrido sólo intervienen 4 columnas por lo que hacemos uso del operador módulo % sobre la posición global.

```
xPos = nPos % 4;
```

Lo que nos dará siempre valores 0, 1, 2, y 3 en ese orden dado que nPos (el número de casilla actual) incrementa de forma continua.

Según el tipo de recorrido vemos que en las líneas impares precisamos que la posición relativa sea 3, 2, 1 y 0 en ese orden; y es por ello que solventamos esta variante con el código:

```
if (y%2 != 0) xPos = 3 - xPos;
```

El resto no precisa de más explicación creo, para la segunda parte del recorrido aplica igual solo que a filas.